# Find the conditional PDF $f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y)$ given the joint PDF and graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is a homework problem. I am currently working with a classmate and we are both stuck on this problem.

The question is problem 21 from the following link:

http://www.athenasc.com/CH4-prob-supp.pdf

We are given that $f_{X, Y}(x,y)= 0.1$ for one-tenth of the graph. We want to calculate $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$. I tried approaching this by using the equality:

- $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = \frac{f_{X, Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$

We are given that $\frac{f_{X, Y}(x,y)} = 0.1$. How could I find $f_X(x)$? Thank yoU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtain $f_X$ by "integrating away" $y$.  From the diagram, this will be over $[-2;2]$ when $-1\leq x\leq 1$ and over $[-1;1]$ when $1< x\leq 2$.

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \int\limits_{-2}^2  f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y & : x\in [-1;1] \\[1ex] \int\limits_{-1}^1  f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y & : x\in (1;2] \end{cases}$$

Take it from there.

Comment: We tried this and we were skeptical because when we integrated over $y \in [-1,1]$ we thought this value would already be included when we integrate over $y \in [-2,2]$. More specifically, if we integrate from $-2 \to 2$, this integration includes the smaller integration from $-1 \to 1$.

Comment: No @DavidSouth ; it is a piecewise function.  It has different values depending on the location of the $x$ ordinate.  Since the joint density is uniform over the shape, the marginal measure will be greater where the cross section is wider.

Comment: Oh shoot, we had this down and didn't feel convinced but your explanation makes it completely clear. Thank you!